# Alfresco: retrieve user info from username

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm looking for APIs to fetch user info given a username.

I'm interested in Java API, serverside template/script root object, webscripts services, or even Share API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Java API: PersonService
- JavaScript & Temmplate (Repo-layer): person-Root Object (current user) or people.getPerson(username)
- REST API (org\alfresco\repository\person\person.get.desc.xml) : GET /api/people/{userName}

Answer (score 0):

For JavaScript APIs you can refer this 
[**Person APIs**](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/4.0_JavaScript_API#People_API)

For All webscripts related to users you can check this link

**[Get User Webscripts](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Repository_RESTful_API_Reference#Get_Person)**

You can use any of this as per your requirements.